# Setting up a rails app on puma, rails, nginx everything is running, but nginx sends error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, puma

I am trying to run a rails app. I followed these instructions: http://luugiathuy.com/2014/11/setup-nginx-puma-on-ubuntu/ to set up a server.

But, when I got to the end, specifically: `puma -e production -d -b unix:///tmp/app_name.sock --pidfile /tmp/puma.pid` Upon running it I got the response:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.16.0 (ruby 2.1.7-p400), codename: Midwinter Nights Trance
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
* Daemonizing...
```

The external IP just kept returning the nginx error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

So, looking elsewhere, I tried: 
`RACK_ENV=production bundle exec puma -p 3000`

And, it seemed that this did more, I got:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.15.3 (ruby 2.1.7-p400), codename: Autumn Arbor Airbrush
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/myusername/myappname/log/production.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /home/myusername/myappname/log/production.log). The log level has bee
n raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
** [Bugsnag] Bugsnag exception handler 3.0.0 ready, api_key=#####################
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

But the external web page returned the same nginx error.

How should I proceed? It seems that things are running but puma and nginx just are not talking?

**EDIT 1**

```
I did:  `sudo chmod -R 0777 /home/myunsername/appname/log/`

Then:

$RACK_ENV=production bundle exec puma -p 3000
```

And, now the output is below and the nginx response at the external IP remains the same.

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.15.3 (ruby 2.1.7-p400), codename: Autumn Arbor Airbrush
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Now, both methods: `RACK_ENV=production bundle exec puma -p 3000` and `puma -e production -d -b unix:///tmp/web-app.sock --pidfile /tmp/puma.pid` create puma processes that don't seem to communicate with nginx but do not return any errors.

**EDIT 2** Checking Logs

I ran:

`cat log/production.log`

and it returned:

`I, [2016-02-02T##:##:##.###### #28802]  INFO -- : ** [Bugsnag] Bugsnag exception handler 3.0.0 ready, api_key=####################`

**EDIT 2.5** Checking More Logs
I ran:

`tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`

and it returned:

`2016/02/02 11:09:52 [emerg] 28220#0: unknown directive "tream" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/web-appname.com:1
2016/02/02 11:10:26 [emerg] 28273#0: unknown directive "tream" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/web-appname.com:1`

Those errors were caused a bit ago from my file missing the first 3 characters, that error has since been fixed. In conclusion: there seem to be no errors in the logs that I have listed above that give me any hints.

**EDIT 3**

My guess currently is that I set up my /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.com file incorrectly. Here is all the naming that I have used.

Currently it is named: **web-app.com**, the url is just the ip address, lets say **https://104.199.155.166/**. My application is in a folder called **web-app**

```
upstream web-app {
  server unix:///tmp/web-app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name web-app; # change to match your URL
  root /home/myusername/web-app/public; # change to match your rails app public folder

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web-app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined in line 1
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

**EDIT 4**

I have made many changes to the above config file, and nothing that I do changes anything. I currently have it at what I believe to be the correct configuration. I am at a loss and would appreciate any suggestions.

**Small question:** if there are other users on the same VM and they may have nginx installed and configure differently, could that be causing the issues?

Comment: Start by fixing the permissions error for the log.

Comment: Did you check the access rights for production.log as mentioend in error

Comment: Can you [check the NGiNX logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706111/where-can-i-find-the-error-logs-of-nginx-using-fastcgi-and-django) and add any relevant lines to the question? In this case the error is probally occuring in NGiNX before the request is even passed on to Puma as you suspect.

Comment: @max thanks for the info on where to find the logs, I have added that info in edit 2.5

Answer (score 0):

You have to create config/puma.rb manually. I recommend reading DigitalOcean's article:
["How To Deploy a Rails App with Puma and Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I'll paste the puma.rb from the article:

```
# config/puma.rb
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 2

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
# bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
# in your case
bind "unix:///tmp/web-app.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

Detail: after setting bind [...] you can just execute

```
$ bundle exec puma RAILS_ENV=production
```

Make sure that the directory shared exists and, within it, folders log and pids,
and that the user `nginx` is using has permission to read them.

A few other tips:

- if you have problems with the empty folders from shared (log and pids) and git, put a `.gitkeep` (empty file) inside both of them.
- you can set server_name (nginx directive) as _ (yes, an underscore) or localhost if you do not have a domain.

Also don't forget to check that your vm has http and https traffic enabled.